# Hebrew support in LaTeX (OS X Yosemite)

Tags: pdftex, hebrew

I managed a few weeks ago to make hebrew work on LaTeX (using TeXShop).
Now I updated to MacTex 2015.
Since the upgrade, the hebrew is gone!
All I get is this non-informative message:
`kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 1+120/600 --dpi 720 rdavidi
mktexpk: don't know how to create bitmap font for rdavidi.
mktexpk: perhaps rdavidi is missing from the map file.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.)
(see the transcript file for additional information)
!pdfTeX error: /usr/texbin/pdflatex (file rdavidi): Font rdavidi at 720 not found`
What can I do to restore hebrew? Or how do I re-install that rdavidi font?
My configuration: MacTex 2015 (with Live Tex installed), TeXShop, rendering via pdfLaTeX. I intend mainly to write in hebrew, a bit english, and a lot of math.

 Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Supposedly [the instructions](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1dC3vK-iFCz_fwCsB9fhYuIF607fw4W9Vu0PdBDhLM0E/edit?pli=1) are:

1. Install MacTex
2. Install Xcode
3. Download http://sourceforge.net/projects/ivritex/files/culmus-latex/. Notice you should download 0.7**r1**.
4. Unpack the archive and load up Terminal; cd to unpacked directory
5. TEXMFDIR is a makefile variable used to point to where we’re going to unpack and install everything - we’re going to use `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local`
6. So, paste this into Terminal:

   `sudo make TEXMFDIR=/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/`

   ...followed by your root password.
7. Write the same line but add install in the end

   `sudo make TEXMFDIR=/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/ install`

Voilà! You should now be able to compile LaTeX files with Hebrew on OS X. Remember to have `\sethebrew` and `\unsethebrew` where you wish to type Hebrew.

Also works for Yosemite (10.10.4).